# How to know which spells my mage can cast?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I have just started my first run of Legends of Grimrock. I have in my party an insectoid mage with 3 points in Ice Magic. The tooltip shows me that, at level 3, it should have a spell, marked with 3 question marks (???). How can I know which spell it is and how to cast it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a few things at play here.

First of all, you need to discover the rune combination for a certain spell to cast it. In-game, you do this by finding scrolls, but you can also discover combinations via experimentation (or searching the Internet). For instance, I discovered the rune for Fireburst through experimentation before I ever found the scroll. Likewise, I experimented and found that the first earth spell just uses a single earth symbol. I imagine ice and wind do the same thing, but haven't had the skill to try them yet.

[image]

However, even if you know the correct rune combination for a spell, you still need to have a high enough skill level in the relevant magic type to cast the spell. That's where the ??? comes in when you're looking at your magic skill levels. Once you've successfully entered the correct rune combo for that spell, the ??? on your skill description will change to the name of the spell.

[image]
Regardless of how or when you discover the rune combo for a spell, you can still only cast spells that your skill is high enough to have "unlocked", and your skill text won't tell you what spell it lets you cast until after you've already cast it. It's a bit frustrating, since I took earth magic hoping it would have some a low level healing spell, as many games seem to tie "healing" to "earth". Instead, I discovered through play that the first Earth spells is actually "poison cloud".

So, via in-game means, you'll just have to discover it as you go. If you want to be able to plan ahead where to put your magic points so you can get to certain spells sooner (and for that matter, even know what spells exist), you'll have to look to an external source [such as this one](http://www.grimrock.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=586).

---

For reference, here are the available spells:

### Air Magic

- Level 4 - **Spell Shock** - *Air*
- Level 9 - **Enchanted Shock Arrow** - *Air, Life, Physicality, Death*
- Level 14 - **Lightning Bolt** - *Air, Spirituality*
- Level 19 - **Invisibility** - *Air, Balance, Death*
- Level 22 - **Shock Shield** - *Air, Balance*

### Earth Magic

- Level 3 - **Poison Cloud** - *Earth*
- Level 7 - **Poison Bolt** - *Earth, Air*
- Level 11 - **Enchanted Poison Arrow** - *Earth, Life, Physicality, Death*
- Level 13 - **Poison Shield** - *Earth, Balance*

### Fire Magic

- Level 2 - **Fire Burst** - *Fire*
- Level 7 - **Enchanted Fire Arrow** - *Fire, Life, Physicality, Death*
- Level 13 - **Fire Ball** - *Fire, Physicality, Air*
- Level 16 - **Fire Shield** - *Fire, Balance*

### Ice Magic

- Level 3 - **Ice Shards** - *Ice, Earth*
- Level 7 - **Enchanted Ice Arrow** - *Ice, Life, Physicality, Death*
- Level 13 - **Frostbolt** - *Ice, Air*
- Level 19 - **Frost Shield** - *Ice, Balance*

### Spellcraft

- Level 5 - **Light** - *Balance, Light*
- Level 5 - **Darkness** - *Balance, Darkness*

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/GrimRockSpells Another Source

Comment: so there are no heal spells :(

Comment: @yx. No, but there are a lot of options for healing. Herbs for healing potions are fairly plentiful. The blue glowing crystals that are on every dungeon level and auto-save your game will fully heal and restore you (they even bring back the dead!) and can be used repeatedly, with a short cooldown. And then there's always the option of finding a safe spot and resting.

Comment: I'm liking the game, but yes, the spellcasting system is really lacking imho (besides, having more than one caster in the group can really mess you up)

Comment: Is there an ingame list of the learned/discovered spells and how you can cast it?
kept old scrolls and made my own notes so far...